# Axis of a glide reflection

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I am currently taking a gap year before starting university and am trying to get a head start by teaching myself some of the course content. As a result I have no one to ask and no solutions to check and I've come across a question that I can't wrap my head around.

Here's the question:

> Show that if $f$ is a glide reflection then there is only one line $L$ such that $f(L)=L$ (I am taking this to mean every point on $L$ satisfies $f(z)=z$); we call this line the axis of $f$. Show that if $f$ is a glide reflection with axis $L$, then $\frac {z+f(z)} 2$ lies on $L$ for every $z$.

Now, the first part I had some difficulty with but eventually got a sort of answer out, I have at least convinced myself of it. However, the second part is causing me more difficulty, here's what I've done so far:

If a complex number $w$ lies on $L$, then by definition $f(w)=w$. So, by setting $w= \frac {z+f(z)} 2$ we want to show that $f \left( \frac {z+f(z)} 2 \right) = \frac {z+f(z)} 2$ for every $z$.

So, taking the LHS: $f \left( \frac {z+f(z)} 2 \right) = a \overline {\frac {z+f(z)} 2} + b$.

Note that we have previously established that the form of a glide reflection is $f(z) = a \bar z + b$. We can work with it further to simplify it down to  $\frac {a \bar z + z + b} 2 + \frac {a \bar b + b} 2$.

Now if we work from the RHS it simplifies to: $\frac {a \bar z + z + b} 2$.

We can see from this that LHS=RHS (which we want to show is true for all $z$) if and only if $a \bar b + b = 0$. Here's what's confusing me, we have previously shown that $a \bar b + b \ne 0$ is a necessary condition for a glide reflection, and that if $a \bar b + b = 0$ then we only have a reflection.

Am I being stupid, have I misunderstood the question or have I fundamentally misunderstood the topic?

This is my first post so if I've done something wrong I apologise.

Oh, and for anyone intersted, the questions are from Beardon's 'Algebra and Geometry' Ex3.4, question 3.

Thanks.

Comment: $f(L)=L$ does not mean $\forall x \in L$, $f(x)=x$. If that were the case, then there would exist no such line $L$, because a glide reflector has the property $\forall x$, $f(x) \ne x$. Instead, $f(L)=L$ means $$\{f(x) \, \bigm| \, x \in L\} = L$$

Comment: how is glide reflection defined?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I'm not really sure what I was doing before. Having thought about it though, the axis is the line we are reflecting in, right? I can now explain the second part geometrically (average coordinates of z and f(z) lie on the line) but I'm struggling to show it algebraically. Thanks for that though, that makes a lot more sense now that I think more about it

Comment: A glide reflection is defined as a reflection, follow by a translation parallel to the line we reflected in.